# React Native for iOS Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode6, react-native

I am working on MAC OSX 10.9.5 (Maverics) and XCode 6.4.

I installed Honeybrew , Node and react-native-cli.

Then, I created a new Project "AwesomeProject".

Finally, I ran it through "react-native run-ios" or directly in XCode.

But, Xcode is saying "Build Failed" with a hell lot of errors like-

1 - Parse and Semantic errors in "RCTBridgeModule.h"

2 - Parse and Semantic errors in "RCTAssert.h"

3 - Parse and Semantic errors in "RCTConvert.h"

So, my question is "Is react-native compatible with Xcode 6.4 or I need XCode 7.0 or above for that ?".

As I am new to iOS development and React Native, I have no idea about this.

Can anybody tell how to resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

From the Getting started page of React Native, in the prerequisites:

> Xcode 7.0 or higher. Open the App Store or go to https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/. This will also install git as well.

Comment: The problem is I am working on Virtual Machine of Mac OSX 10.9.5. And, It doesn't support XCode 7.0

Comment: Then, if I were you... I would focus on developing with React Native Android, since you're just getting started.
If you're new to React, there are a lot of things to see. Then maybe you can buy a hackintosh which would be much cheaper than a Mac ^^

Comment: Yeah Ok. Thanks for the help